# TV Wall mount permanent bracket arcs forward

Tags: drywall, mounting, television, brackets, mount

Last night I installed the TV mount bracket on the drywall with two stud support. This was my first ever D.I.Y. lol. Meanwhile, it looks all fine and everything is in place but I noticed that the permanent bracket on which upper hooks are placed is arced forward like a bow and not clinging tightly on to the wall like I hoped (Picture attached). There is a gap between middle of the bracket and the wall. Can this be because of TV weight? My LED is 42' inches and bracket is rated for 37-70' TVs. Is this normal to have some elasticity in the brackets?
or do I need to add more support in the middle?

[image: l]

Comment: I can’t tell if that is normal or not if your bracket is sized for the tv it should be ok I have a 78 or 82” in my front room on a bracket. If the rail itself is what you are pointing out you may need to pull it in tighter or add washers to distribute the force from the screws across the rail.

Comment: Yes, the rail is pointing out as if TV is pulling it towards itself. Do you mean that I should add washers and screws in the middle to push it against the wall?

Comment: It looks as though you've mounted the bracket to the studs near each side/edge. Is there another stud somewhere closer to the middle of the bracket which you could screw into in addition to the ones you've already done?

Comment: @brhans Correct. These studs are 24' apart. I am afraid there are no studs between the studs that I have drilled in. I wonder if I could add additional screws in the middle using hollow wall anchors just to add a bit of support.

Comment: I am not talking about the width, but a washer in each of the rails or cranking them in tighter so there is no flex at the point of contact for the screws. If everything matches up and you kinda snugged the screws many times lag bolts you need washers and a bit more torque and that should secure the rail. As I said I have a very large flat screen in my family room a 65” in my bed room and I think a similar rail system but they are screwed in tight with no problem in either for 5 years in our 1930’s house both on internal 24” walls.

Comment: When I fasten the brackets to the TV I like to fasten them as high as they will go without being visible so the top of the TV doesn't have a tendency to "lean" forward and pull on the bracket.

Comment: It's unlikely the metal will break.  So long as your screws are tight into studs this doesn't seem like a "problem". If it really bugs you, buy a better stand.  Pick something that is literally "heavy" instead of the cheapest one available. The metal will be thicker.    I wouldn't install drywall anchors... IMO It's just a matter of time before they'll get pulled out and leave you with more mess to fix later.